# MySQL join with two columns looking at same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the fields:

```
orderID
collection
delivery
username
```

collection and delivery are IDs and correspond to a record in the addresses table:

```
addressID
address1
address2
address3
town
country
```

How can I write a query that shows all orders for a particular username but with the full address details for both collection and delivery.

Comment: select orders.* , address1 as collection_address1, addresses.address1 as delivery_name from orders 
left join addresses on orders.delivery=addresses.addressID 
where username='chris'

But I just get the same address for both collection and delivery :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add an alias to you joined tables.

```
select * from orders 
join addresses collections on orders.collection = collections.addressID 
join addresses deliveries on orders.delivery = deliveries.addressID
where username=<username>
```

Comment: Hi

select * from orders 
join addresses collections on orders.collection = collection.addressID 
join addresses deliveries on orders.delivery = deliveries.addressID

Gives me: "Unknown column 'collection.addressID' in 'on clause'"

select * from orders 
join addresses collections on orders.collection = addresses.addressID 
join addresses deliveries on orders.delivery = addresses.addressID

Gives me: "Unknown column 'addresses.addressID' in 'on clause'"

It must almost be there though?

Comment: Yes sorry, I fix that. I didn't test it... You see the word after join addresses? That's the alias which you should use in the on clause

Comment: I'm not sure of your requirements, maybe you shouldn't use this query as it is: you might want to use left join instead of join, and you'll probably have to add some aliases in the select clause too

Comment: Thanks, I have added aliases. I assume a left join would be used in case there is an order without a corresponding address in the addresses table?

Comment: Exactly, if you use a standard join orders without addresses won't be returned by the query

Comment: Left join it is then! Thank you very much, I appreciate your help.